# Need help fixing height discrepancy in LaTeX tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Why do these tables not have the same height, even though the number of rows is the same? I am trying to place them into a cell of a larger table, but for some reason, they are not the same height. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}[t]{cllcc}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
1 & A-1, A-2 & B-1, B-2, B-3 & 10.5 & 1.2 \\
2 & A-3, A-4 & B-4, B-5, B-6 & 8.2 & 0.9 \\
3 & A-2, A-4 & B-2, B-4, B-6 & 9.6 & 1.1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}[t]{cllcc}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
4 & A-5 & B-7, B-8, B-9 & 12.1 & 1.5 \\
5 & A-1, A-4 & B-2, B-5, B-8 & 11.3 & 1.3 \\
6 & A-3 & B-1, B-3, B-6, B-9 & 7.8 & 0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

[image: mwe]

Your MWE has several issues:

- Use of `\resizebox`. Never do this. Apparently the right table is a little bit wider than the left one, so it is shrunk more. Accordingly, the font size within it is smaller.
- Nesting minipage in `tabular` is not a good idea. Instead, it is better to use the `p{<width>}` column type.
- Due to the small default size of `\textwidth`, you need to reduce the font size inside the tables to `\scriptsize`. This make the tables hard to read... See if you can change the page layout with the `geometry` package and increase `\textwidth`.
- If you like to use `minipage`s, then remove the outer table as is done in the MWE below and use `tabular*` for the inner tables.

MWE that produces the tables shown above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \scriptsize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cllcc}
    \toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
1 & A-1, A-2 & B-1, B-2, B-3 & 10.5 & 1.2 \\
2 & A-3, A-4 & B-4, B-5, B-6 & 8.2 & 0.9 \\
3 & A-2, A-4 & B-2, B-4, B-6 & 9.6 & 1.1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cllcc}
    \toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
4 & A-5 & B-7, B-8, B-9 & 12.1 & 1.5 \\
5 & A-1, A-4 & B-2, B-5, B-8 & 11.3 & 1.3 \\
6 & A-3 & B-1, B-3, B-6, B-9 & 7.8 & 0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- However, for your tables you don't need minipages at all. The table body could be as follows:

```
    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular*}{0.49\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cllcc}
    \toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
1 & A-1, A-2 & B-1, B-2, B-3 & 10.5 & 1.2 \\
2 & A-3, A-4 & B-4, B-5, B-6 & 8.2 & 0.9 \\
3 & A-2, A-4 & B-2, B-4, B-6 & 9.6 & 1.1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\hfill
   \begin{tabular*}{0.49\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cllcc}
    \toprule
\textbf{ID} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{A}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\bm{Type_\mathrm{B}}$} & \textbf{Length} & \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
4 & A-5 & B-7, B-8, B-9 & 12.1 & 1.5 \\
5 & A-1, A-4 & B-2, B-5, B-8 & 11.3 & 1.3 \\
6 & A-3 & B-1, B-3, B-6, B-9 & 7.8 & 0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
```

Resulted tables are the same as before.

Comment: @steve, thank you for editing.

Answer (score 4):

With standard fonts and no scaling, the first table has width 228.30536pt and the second one 249.83318pt (I removed the padding on either side in both).

At `\scriptsize` (which is really small), I get 190.83781pt and 208.06706pt.

Thus, if you want to set them side by side, you need a text width of at least 400pt, a bit over 14cm (5.5in).

Here's the output when the text width is set to 6in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{textwidth=6in}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cllcc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{A}}$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{B}}$} &
  \textbf{Length} &
  \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
1 & A-1, A-2 & B-1, B-2, B-3 & 10.5 & 1.2 \\
2 & A-3, A-4 & B-4, B-5, B-6 & 8.2 & 0.9 \\
3 & A-2, A-4 & B-2, B-4, B-6 & 9.6 & 1.1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cllcc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{A}}$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{B}}$} &
  \textbf{Length} &
  \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
4 & A-5 & B-7, B-8, B-9 & 12.1 & 1.5 \\
5 & A-1, A-4 & B-2, B-5, B-8 & 11.3 & 1.3 \\
6 & A-3 & B-1, B-3, B-6, B-9 & 7.8 & 0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how I solved the boldface headers ***without*** `\bm`.

A better idea, in my opinion, would be to typeset the two tables one above the other (and as a single table).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cllcc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{A}}$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{B}}$} &
  \textbf{Length} &
  \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
1 & A-1, A-2 & B-1, B-2, B-3 & 10.5 & 1.2 \\
2 & A-3, A-4 & B-4, B-5, B-6 & 8.2 & 0.9 \\
3 & A-2, A-4 & B-2, B-4, B-6 & 9.6 & 1.1 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\addlinespace[\normalbaselineskip]
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\textbf{ID} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{A}}$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$\mathit{Type}_{\mathrm{B}}$} &
  \textbf{Length} &
  \textbf{Weight}\\
\midrule
4 & A-5 & B-7, B-8, B-9 & 12.1 & 1.5 \\
5 & A-1, A-4 & B-2, B-5, B-8 & 11.3 & 1.3 \\
6 & A-3 & B-1, B-3, B-6, B-9 & 7.8 & 0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]